# Rockbox audio format

Tags: c, audio, rockbox

How do you specify a callback for `rb->pcm_play_data()`?

Answer (score 8):

The prototype for the callback function is as follows:

```
static void my_audio_callback(const void **start, size_t *size);
```

`*start` should be set to point to the region of memory where your PCM data is stored (16-bit signed integers), and `*size` should be the size of this region.

Once you've written your callback, call `rb->pcm_play_data()`, and enjoy the music!

```
rb->pcm_play_data(my_audio_callback, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

A very late edit: The format of the auto is 16-bit signed integer PCM, with stereo interleave (even indexes: left channel, odd: right).